# Concat with merged Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, concatenation

I was wondering if there was a more or less out of the box method to complete the following. I could write it myself but would prefer if there was a neet way to do this. I've got 2 or more arrays. Each Entry of this array can contain either a String or an Object which will also have an array as Value. Like this

```
var arr1 = ["Title", {Person: ["Name", "Age"]}]
var arr2 = ["Title", {Person: ["Sex]}]
```

Now i want to do more or less a concat of those too. But instead of

```
["Title", "Title" , {Person : ["Name", "Age"]},{Person, ["Sex"]}]
```

I want to get

```
["Title", {Person: ["Name", "Age", "Sex"]}]
```

For just getting unique concats there is plenty of stuff to find (e.g. https://github.com/thlorenz/unique-concat) but i would still end up with 2 person objects. Do you know any framework to do this or can you think of a lean way to do this out of the box?

Comment: thanks for the quick replies. One thing I forgot to mention. I'd need a pretty generic approach. So the object won't be person all the time, but can be any random Key, also the strings in the array can vary

Answer (score 2):

Since, you have mentioned that you have two objects, there is no need to use any other plugins or scripts. Simply use **spread syntax** as `...arr2[1].Person` to push those values in `arr1`:

```js
var arr1 = ["Title", {Person: ["Name", "Age"]}]
var arr2 = ["Title", {Person: ["Sex"]}]
arr1[1].Person.push(...arr2[1].Person);
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using ES6, array spread.

```
arr1[1].Person = [...arr1[1].Person, ...arr2[1].Person];
```

Answer (score 0):

To cope with the `unique` bit, you can use a `Set`

eg..

```js
var arr1 = ["Title", {Person: ["Name", "Age"]}]
var arr2 = ["Title", {Person: ["Sex", "Age"]}]
arr1[1].Person = Array.from(
  new Set([...arr2[1].Person, ...arr1[1].Person])
);
console.log(arr1);
```